# Bootstrap Footer Columns stacking and loosing footer colour

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, background, footer

Basically I have made a footer with a black background. I have 3 Col-4's in it with various info in them. On the desktop it looks fine, but on mobile, the columns stack, which I want. When they stack the footer doesn't go further so it has a large white section underneath. I was wondering if anyone could take a look and suggest something. The codes probably messy, as i am a newbie.

```css
#footer {
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: #000000;
 width: 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<footer>
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
<br>
<br>
Home<br>
Services<br>
Gallery<br>
About<br>
Contact
 </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <aligncenter>Check Out Our Other pages</aligncenter><br>
      <aligncenter2><img src="Facebook-icon.png" width="50" height="51" alt=""/><br>
    <img src="YouTube-icon-full_color.png" width="50" height="36" alt=""/><br>
    <img src="new-instagram-icon-topic.png" width="50" height="48" alt=""/></aligncenter2>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="container-fluid" 
<br>
<br>
<alignright>
Registered office<br>
 
14 Stott Court<br>
 
Tweedmouth<br>
 
Berwick-Upon-Tweed<br>
 
Northumberland<br>
 
TD152YP
</alignright>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the mobile cols in Bootstrap you can change the

> "col-sm-*"

to the value you need it will work on the small screen only.

```css
#footer {
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: #000000;
 width: 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<footer>
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
<br>
<br>
Home<br>
Services<br>
Gallery<br>
About<br>
Contact
 </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <aligncenter>Check Out Our Other pages</aligncenter><br>
      <aligncenter2><img src="Facebook-icon.png" width="50" height="51" alt=""/><br>
    <img src="YouTube-icon-full_color.png" width="50" height="36" alt=""/><br>
    <img src="new-instagram-icon-topic.png" width="50" height="48" alt=""/></aligncenter2>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="container-fluid" 
<br>
<br>
<alignright>
Registered office<br>
 
14 Stott Court<br>
 
Tweedmouth<br>
 
Berwick-Upon-Tweed<br>
 
Northumberland<br>
 
TD152YP
</alignright>
      </div>
```